# Why do the estimated values of the latent variables using lavPredict look completely different from the calculated scale scores?

Tags: r, structural-equation-model

I don't understand why the estimated values via lavPredict look completely different from the "original" sum scores of the questionnaires? Are the values standardised via lavPredict?

```
factor_values <- lavPredict(fit)
```

**Calculated questionnare scores**

142

139

122

134

**Estimated questionnare scores**

0.11513018

0.18437756

-0.03589164

0.18019289

Answer (score 0):

"original sum scores" have measurement error, whereas factor score estimates have measurement error parsed out.

https://doi.org/10.1177/0013164415607618

However, they still contain error due to indeterminacy.

https://doi.org/10.1007/s11336-019-09677-2

https://doi.org/10.1080/00273171.2018.1535420

Regarding the location and scales of sum scores, they are based on the observed response scale.  Factor scores are estimated on whatever arbitrary metric you specified in the model (e.g., *M*=0, *SD*=1).

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. I have not explicitly set a metric. By default, the metric in Lavaan seems to be set to M = 0 and SD = 1. I am a bit confused. Actually, isn't the default function of lavaan that the factor loading is set to 1, which should also take the metric of the manifest variables/items. Why is that not the case here?

Comment: It might just be more straight-forward for `lavaan` to calculate them as standard normal.  Again, the metric is arbitrary, and it is not based on the observed-variable metric.

Comment: hm.. in our info from our university it says: "In the theory section you have heard that in models with latent variables either a factor loading or the latent variance must always be fixed in order to give the latent variable a scale. Either a factor loading is set to 1 in order to apply the scale of the manifest variable to the latent variable, or the latent variance is fixed to 1 in order to make the latent variable interpretable in z-values". In the end, however, it makes no difference for further calculations whether the estimated factorvalues are z-values or in the "original" metric (?).